how does rioxarray reproject match resample the data?
What method is used to resample within rioxarray reproject match? Looking into resampling in rioxarray it seems to use rasterio which defaults to nearest resampling. Should I assume this is what is used in this method? Is there a way to specify a different method within reproject match?

As described in the docs, it defaults to "nearest" but you can use any available resampling method that rasterio provides.
https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/html/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.raster_dataset.RasterDataset.reproject_match
https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.enums.html#rasterio.enums.Resampling
